# wordpress nav menu does not recognize single-post as child of a term

Tags: wordpress, menu, highlight, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a problem and I'm pulling my hair out over it.

I have a vertical nav menu which lists a taxonomy's terms and child terms.

The child terms all own a set of posts.

Upon visiting a single-post page, the menu defaults to top level and doesn't recognize that the single post is a child of any menu item. (i.e. belongs to a tax term in the menu)

Does anyone know how to have a wordpress nav menu recognize when the single post currently being displayed is a child of a term in the menu?

These pics should clarify:

Here I'm viewing gallery of items for term "filigree" child-term "rings"
[image: Viewing gallery of items for term filigree child-term rings]

After Clicking on a single ring, the menu retracts to default and no highlight to show current state
[image: Click on a single ring and menu retracts to default and no highlight]

Note that "our products" is always bold and not part of the menu. (don't get me started on that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around to solve this, thought I'd post it in case it's useful to anobody else out there. Here is my code:

```
 <?php 
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'products');


    if( is_single() ){  ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function(){
                jQuery('.menu').find(":contains('<?php echo $terms[1]->name; ?>')").show().addClass('current-menu-item');
            });         
        </script>
        <?php 
    }

?>

    </body>
```

Note that 'products' is a taxonomy name and the jQuery selector simply parses my `<ul>` of menu items, finds a child element containing the target term and adds the class which wordpress uses to mark the current menu item 'current-menu-item'